# How to cancel a timer from another scene JAVA

Tags: java, timer, timertask

I have tried reading the java docs and have done quite some research but none works. Basically, when I change a scene, I want the timer to cancel.
Code for timer.Omitted the part where I created the timer. When I initialize, I will call the timer timerUpdateLiveInfo():

```
private void timerUpdateLiveInfo() {
    t1.schedule(tt1, 0,5000);
}

TimerTask tt1=new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                PendingOrders.setText(String.valueOf(orderDB.getNumOfOrder()));
                String record = orderDB.getTopCanteens();
                //System.out.println(orderDB.getTopCanteens());
                String[] fields = record.split(";"); // attributes separated by ;
                String canteenTop=fields[0];
                String canteenTop2=fields[1];
                String canteenTop3=fields[2];
                MostPopularLabel1.setText(canteenTop);
                MostPopularLabel2.setText(canteenTop2);
                MostPopularLabel3.setText(canteenTop3);
            }
        });
    }
};
```

When I try to cancel "locally", from a button it works.

```
@FXML
void handleTestingButton(ActionEvent event) {
    cancelTimer();
}
```

and

```
public void cancelTimer() {
    tt1.cancel();
    t1.cancel();
    System.out.println("Cancelled");
    t2.cancel();
}
```

However, when I try to call using another fxml after it changes scene, the timer still continues to run:

```
public void handleReturnToUser(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
    WorkerHomeController workerHome= new WorkerHomeController();
    workerHome.cancelTimer();
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/ooppFinalProject/view/HomePage1.fxml"));
    myScene = (Scene) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene();
    Stage stage = (Stage) (myScene).getWindow();
    Parent nextView = loader.load();
    workerHome.cancelTimer();

    stage.setScene(new Scene(nextView));
    stage.setTitle("Home Page");
    stage.show();
}
```

Please help. Thank you very much!

Updated:

```
    public void handleReturnToUser(ActionEvent event) throws IOException{
    //workerHome.cancelTimer();
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/ooppFinalProject/view/HomePage1.fxml"));
    myScene = (Scene) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene();
    Stage stage = (Stage) (myScene).getWindow();
    Parent nextView = loader.load();
    //workerHome.cancelTimer();

    WorkerHomeController workerHome=loader.getController();
    workerHome.cancelTimer();

    stage.setScene(new Scene(nextView));
    stage.setTitle("Home Page");
    stage.show();
}
```

And Stack Trace:

```
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: ooppFinalProject.controller.HomePage1Controller cannot be cast to ooppFinalProject.controller.WorkerHomeController
at ooppFinalProject.controller.WorkerSideTabController.handleReturnToUser(WorkerSideTabController.java:91)
... 62 more
```

Comment: WorkerHomeController workerHome= new WorkerHomeController();
is this the instance of the timer you wanna cancel?
I did not see you passing it as the new controller, so it cancels the wrong one...

Comment: Yes I am trying to cancel that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/ooppFinalProject/view/HomePage1.fxml"));
myScene = (Scene) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene();
Stage stage = (Stage) (myScene).getWindow();
Parent nextView = loader.load();
WorkerHomeController workerHome=loader.getController();
workerHome.cancelTimer();
```

explanation: you need to call `workerHome.cancelTimer();` on the `WorkerHomeController` that is in fact the controller creat when `loader.load();` and you get it by `loader.getController();`

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your help. But I think the current problem here is that I have 3 fxml files + controller. Let me explain.

1. WorkerHome.fxml + Controller
2. WorkerSideTab.fxml + Controller
3. HomePage1.fxml + Controller

So my timer is running in WorkerHome and to go to HomePage1, I have to click from the worker side tab. It is not local as explained earlier and hence I cannot call it directly. I also cannot call the method in WorkerHome as I am trying to load up HomePage1. Have attached stack trace above for your reference.

Thank you very much for your help! :)

Comment: Not sure I understood, but what I recommend, 
HomePage1 homePage1=loader.getController();
homePage1.setWorkerHomeController (WorkerHomeController)
homePage1.cancelTimer();
and homePage1.cancelTimer() it infact
myWorkerHomeController.cancelTimer()

Comment: May I know what this line is for?
homePage1.setWorkerHomeController (WorkerHomeController)

Comment: If there is an upper layer that recognizes this instance it could have sent it to the new controller

Comment: I tried the above method which I suppose is casting but it dosen't work. Also, I tried loading up the controller for the WorkerHome itself without changing scene also does not work. I'm sorry

Comment: no casting... the controller have to be the type that defined in  fx:controller="..." in fxml file

Comment: Hmm... I'm so sorry but I have tried everything I could. I even shifted it to another tab(another button) in my side tab, so that it won't even change page because I thought the part where it was changing page might be the issue. I guess I will move the codes back "locally" and place it on the hamburger bar instead bcos I can't seem to make it work from anywhere else from other fxml pages. Thank you very much for your help!!! Much appreciated!!! :)

Comment: If one timer is enough , you may consider making him static

Comment: Yea that did the trick thank you so much for your help! :) Really really appreciate your help! All the best in your life!